# Is it possible to use two "job.properties" file in a workflow oozie?

Tags: hadoop, workflow, oozie, properties-file

I need to use another file than the job.properties for my workflow. This file have the same structure than a properties file. I have a generator of result's path which create this file. The particularity of this one, is that it's change each time the workflow is launched (with new inputs files). And in my workflow, I need to delete these paths before execute mys pig script.

But, I don't know how to "tell" to my workflow that I have others variables in another file than job.properties.

Have you got a solution ?

Thanks
Angelique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove the Path in the Pig it Self or You can call fs action in the workflow before executing the Pig Action, both will work.

for Pig mention rmf command at the beging of the file :
rmf

in workflow:

```
<action name="prepare">
<fs>
<delete path="${pig output}"/>
</fs>
<ok to="pigAction"/>
<error to="prepareFailed"/>
</action>
<kill name="prepareFailed">
<message>Clean Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! I didn't know that we can put some shell action directly in pig !! It will save me a lot of time !!